# Numpy array change value of inner elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I create an array in numpy as

```
a = np.ones([5 , 5])
```

I will then get an output as 5x5 array full of 1s. I would like to keep the outer elements as 1, and inner elements as 0. So I would like output to be:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

Is there any way with which we could do this in a single line? (I have read about inner() but I dont know how to get it working with this single array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can use *slicing* for this:

```
a[1:-1, 1:-1] = 0
```

Or for a generic multidimensional array:

```
a[(slice(1, -1),) * a.ndim] = 0
```

but usually it would be better to construct such matrix in another way. This produces:

```
>>> a = np.ones([5 , 5])
>>> a[1:-1, 1:-1] = 0
>>> a
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

and for instance for a 3d case (imagine some sort of cube):

```
>>> a = np.ones([5 , 5, 5])
>>> a[(slice(1, -1),) * a.ndim] = 0
>>> a
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]]])
```

Comment: Can also spell it `a[np.s_[1:-1,] * a.ndim] = 0`

Comment: @Eric: true, but behind the curtains, `np.s_[1:-1,]` simply returns a `(slice(1,-1),)` tuple, so it will only cost more computational resources, and furthermore more dependency on numpy whereas `slice` is a vanilla Python class.

Comment: Depending on numpy in the context of preparing a numpy array doesn't sound like a problem to me. It may actually be faster, because python can load the slice in a single opcode, rather then having to call the `slice` function

Comment: @Eric: yes, but here you call the `__getitem__` from the `s_` attribute.

Comment: @Eric: I tested it, with numpy (`return s_[1:-1]`) it takes `2.986656811001012s` for 10M runs, for `return (slice(1, -1),)`, it takes 1.8174990950210486s.